# Sequential Unbind/Bind Click

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I have 5 div classes (button1, button2, button3, button4, button5)

What I want is that all classes are not clickable onload (except button1) and then after button1 is clicked, button2 is active and the others are not and so on.

So a sequential click through of sorts.

HTML

```
<map name="Map" id="Map"> 
  <area id="button" title="HAT" alt="HAT" href="#" shape="poly" coords="xxx,xxx" /> 
  <area id="button2" title="SUN CREAM" alt="SUN CREAM" href="#" shape="poly" coords="xxx,xxx" /> 
</map>
```

I tried:

```
$(function(){ $("#button2").unbind("click"); });
```

as the initial function, and then under button1 click function:

```
$("#button1").click(function() { 
$("#Map #button2").bind("click");
});
```

This works in that it doesnt allow button2 to be clicked, but even after clicking button1 it still cannot be clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please share your html code?

Comment: use a class to `button` and on current button click event do `$(this).next().bind("click");` and for unbind all use `$(".btn").unbind("click");`

Comment: Doesnt make sense - I need all IDs unbind (except for the button1) and then once button1 has been clicked I need button2 to again be clickable (bind)

Comment: why don't you share your html code and let us help you ?

Comment: HTML code I am interacting with: 

<map name="Map" id="Map">
 <area id="button" title="HAT" alt="HAT" href="#" shape="poly" coords="xxx,xxx" />
 <area id="button2" title="SUN CREAM" alt="SUN CREAM" href="#" shape="poly" coords="xxx,xxx" />
</map>

Comment: where is your `button1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In more generalized and constructive approach, implementing jQuery plugin:

```
$("#button1").sequence("click")
    .handle(function () {
        alert("YOU...")
    })
    .handleNext("#button2", function () {
        alert("SHALL...")
    })
    .handleNext("#button3", function () {
        if (prompt("NOT PASS!!!") != "I'm Frodo, drunkie!") {
            alert("BZZZZZZZT!");
            return this.runBackward();
        }
        alert("Ah, oh, okaay...");
    })
    .handleNext("#button4", function () {
        alert("Pwned! ]:-}");
        this.resetSequence();
    });
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("#button1").sequence("click")
        .handle(function () {
            alert("YOU...")
        })
        .handleNext("#button2", function () {
            alert("SHALL...")
        })
        .handleNext("#button3", function () {
            if (prompt("NOT PASS!!!") != "I'm Frodo, drunkie!") {
                alert("BZZZZZZZT!");
                return this.runBackward();
            }
            alert("Ah, oh, okaay...");
        })
        .handleNext("#button4", function () {
            alert("Pwned! ]:-}");
            this.resetSequence();
        });

});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.sequence = function (event) {
        this.sequencer = {
            event: event,
            plugged: this,
            disable : function (element, enable) {
                $(element).attr("disabled", (enable !== false) ? "disabled" : false);
            },
            disablePrev: function (enable) {
                if (this.prevInSequence)
                    this.disable(this.prevInSequence, enable);
            },
            disableNext: function (enable) {
                if (this.nextInSequence)
                    this.disable(this.nextInSequence, enable);
            },
            hasPrev : function (prev) {
                this.prevInSequence = prev;
            },
            hasNext : function (next) {
                this.nextInSequence = next;
                this.plugged.resetSequence();
            },
            process : function (callback, event) {
                this.disablePrev();
                if (callback.call(this.plugged, event) === false)
                    return;
                this.disable(this.plugged);
                this.disableNext(false);
            },
            reset: function () {
                this.disablePrev(false);
                if (this.nextInSequence)
                    this.nextInSequence.sequencer.reset();
                this.disable(this.plugged);
            }
        };

        this.resetSequence = function () {
            this.sequencer.disable(this, false);
            this.sequencer.disableNext(this);

            if (this.sequencer.prevInSequence)
                this.sequencer.prevInSequence.resetSequence();
        }

       this.handle = function (callback) {
            var self = this;
            this.on(this.sequencer.event, function (e) {
                if (self.attr("disabled"))
                    return;
                self.sequencer.process.call(self.sequencer, callback, e);
            });
            return this;
        }
        this.handleNext = function (selector, callback) {
            var next = $(selector);
            var sequence = next.sequence(this.sequencer.event).handle(callback);
            this.sequencer.hasNext(next);
            sequence.sequencer.hasPrev(this);
            return sequence;
        }
        this.runBackward = function () {
            this.sequencer.reset();
            return false;
        }

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button id="button1">1</button>
  <button id="button2">2</button>
  <button id="button3">3</button>
  <button id="button4">Finish</button>
```

Comment: Fixed bug when `disabled` attr being ignored on `area` elements. Se code update in `this.handle(calback)` implementation.

Comment: OK, that works great - but it also allows you to go back to button1 (if you go to button2) ... you cannot go back only forwards...

Comment: Updated code to block back-clicking and refactored it a little.

Comment: Great - thank you. One other request you also cannot click the same link twice. So with this if you click button1 you can also click it again. After clicking button1 you have to move onto button2

Comment: Updated. You'd better both accept _and_ upvote my answer, or I'll be sad T_T

Comment: Is there a way to detect if they do try to click another button it plays a sound? So if they click button3 for example, but they are on button2. Which part of the code can I put that into?

Comment: see `if (self.attr("disabled")) return;`? replace that `return` with something like `{ alert("DONG!"); return; }`

Comment: One more question - if i add an aria-role="tab" to the map area it destroys the click on the object - any suggestions?

Comment: Debug. Open debugger console, put breakpoints into click-handlers and debug click handling step by step. Also, that can be some other pluggin/code, that intercepts clicks in own handlers and calls `e.preventDefault()` or smth. and make rest ob binded click event-handlers to never been called.

Comment: Any suggestions though? The code in question is for an accessibility page - so VoiceOver is on - works fine on desktop I think - it is just with the IOS voiceover...

Comment: Well, [googling](https://google.com/?q=ios%20voiceover%20image%20area%20click%20event%20not%20fired) it tippet that it is [default](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8271) behavior for clicks in ios with voiceover, [maybe](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/8272) was fixed in `jquery-mobile v1.5`, and [probably](https://www.marcozehe.de/2013/04/24/easy-aria-tip-6-making-clickables-accessible/) has another workarounds, but if they don't work - you really should start it as separate question, 'cose it _is_ separate question and _maybe_ there is sombody who knows better...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like [Document](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").unbind("click",function(){
      alert("unbind click");
    });
  
});

function btnClick(thisObj){
    //unbind all not current
     $(".btn").not(thisObj).unbind("click");
     //bind next btn
     $(thisObj).next().bind("click",function(){
      alert("bind click");
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" name="btn1" value="1" onclick="btnClick(this);">
<input type="button" class="btn" name="btn2"  value="2"  onclick="btnClick(this);">
<input type="button" class="btn" name="btn3"  value="3"  onclick="btnClick(this);">
<input type="button" class="btn" name="btn4"  value="4"  onclick="btnClick(this);">
<input type="button" class="btn" name="btn5"  value="5"  onclick="btnClick(this);">
```

Comment: Pushed "3" couple of times, pushed "4" and get couple of alerts immediately.

Comment: Please check updated as `$(".btn")` bind for all so alerts multiple. I made changes with separate click event

Comment: Doesnt work for me - tried applying to my image map but nothing happens. ie. <area class="btn" id="button">

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can disable the clicked button and enable the next button, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Map').find('area').not('#button').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#Map area').on("click",function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        $(this).next('area').removeAttr('disabled');
    }); 
});
```